# how to modify Datagram raw TCP IP?

Tags: c++

I'm modifing a Datagram raw TCP IP, because I want to change the cookie of a web page, when I modified the datagram the browser hangs, So I think that could be, maybe because I´m not updating all TCP IP necessary Headers, I updated the PAYLOAD SIZE, IP Total length, IP Checksum, I dont see if I need change another one.  Maybe because the IP length is 1470 and after the changes is 1481, and that's in the edge (1500). I dont know, somebody can helps?.

I'm using divert sockets, that why I change in TCP IP

Comment: so if you don't modify the datagram, it doesn't hang?

Comment: yes, without change is doesn't hang.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is the payload of TCP/IP, another thing is the content of the payload, which in this case is a webpage. If your goal is to change the web page, you are doing an HTTP proxy filtering and you must adhere to the HTTP protocol.
For example, if you change the body of an HTTP response, you must also change the field Content-length in the header of the response, otherwise the behaviour of the browser is unpredictable.
Similar problems arise in other scenarios.
If you want to filter a webpage, you could use a proxy, just try a Google search.
One of most popular Window Proxy Filter has been Proxomitron.
Also, node.js can be run as a proxy filter. Not to cite the pletora of implementation of proxy filter in python or perl.

Comment: I'm not modifying the content HTTP, I just modifying the headers, so I don't have the udpate the content-length, do I?. I want to change the value of a cookie. Actually I'm creating my own proxy, and it works fine. But I want to change the cookie.

Comment: I see the problem in the acknowledgment and sequence, it doesn't increase to response when I modified the raw.

Comment: Try to not change data at TCP level but at Application level, if your intent is to modidy HTTP information